# Output only the first pattern-line and its following line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I need to filter the output of a command.
I tried this.

```
bpeek | grep nPDE
```

My problem is that I need all matches of `nPDE` and the line after the found file.  So the output would be like:

```
iteration nPDE
1         1
iteration nPDE
2         4
```

The best case would be if it would show me the found line only once and then only the line after it.

I found solutions with awk, But as far as I know awk can only read files.

Comment: wrt - `as far as i know awk can only read files`. Not at all, it can read from pipes just like `grep` can and it can also read from sub-processes and co-processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for that.

```
grep --help
...
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
```

Therefore:

```
bpeek | grep -A 1 'nPDE'
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk (for completeness since you have grep and sed solutions):

```
awk '/nPDE/{c=2} c&&c--'
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -A` works if your grep supports it (it's not in [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)). If it doesn't, you can use sed:

```
bpeek | sed '/nPDE/!d;N'
```

which does the following:

```
/nPDE/!d # If the line doesn't match "nPDE", delete it (starts new cycle)
N        # Else, append next line and print them both
```

Notice that this would fail to print the right output for this file

```
nPDE
nPDE
context line
```

If you have GNU sed, you can use an address range as follows:

```
sed '/nPDE/,+1!d'
```

Addresses of the format `addr1,+N` define the range between *`addr1`* (in our case `/nPDE/`) and the following *`N`* lines. This solution is easier to adapt to a different number of context lines, but still fails with the example above.

A solution that manages cases like

```
blah
nPDE
context
blah
blah
nPDE
nPDE
context
nPDE
```

would like like

```
sed -n '/nPDE/{$p;:a;N;/\n[^\n]*nPDE[^\n]*$/!{p;b};ba}'
```

doing the following:

```
/nPDE/ {                       # If the line matches "nPDE"
    $p                         # If we're on the last line, just print it
    :a                         # Label to jump to
    N                          # Append next line to pattern space
    /\n[^\n]*nPDE[^\n]*$/! {   # If appended line does not contain "nPDE"
        p                      # Print pattern space
        b                      # Branch to end (start new loop)
    }
    ba                         # Branch to label (appended line contained "nPDE")
}
```

All other lines are not printed because of the `-n` option.

As pointed out in Ed's comment, this is neither readable nor easily extended to a larger amount of context lines, but works correctly for one context line.

Comment: That doesn't have the same semantics as the grep or awk solution - if `nPDE` can appear on 2 consecutive lines then it'll print those 2 lines but won't print the line after the 2nd `nPDE` line. The grep and awk solutions would print all 3 lines. Just sayin'....

Comment: IMHO it's not worth worrying about since this isn't really a task you'd use sed for anyway. Imagine the requirements changed to print 10 lines after `nPDE` - typing `sed '/nPDE/!d;N;N;N;N;N;N.....` would get old pretty fast :-) vs just changing the number in the grep or awk solution.

Comment: @EdMorton ...there! Mostly proving the point that you should use awk instead ;)